# shear flow changes

Tags: structural-engineering

in tthe notes , It's stated that the shear flow will be varies lineraly prependicular to the direction of shear force , V . But , in the phooto, it shoed that the shear flow will be varies parabolically prependicular to the direction of shear force ...
Which is correct ? the notes or the example in the  photo ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Meta is for questions about meta-aspects of running the site.  This appears to be a question intended for the main engineering site, so I'm migrating it there.

Comment: the figure agrees with the text. What are you asking?

Comment: Can  you  prove  and  explain  why  the  shear flow  has  the  linear  shape  on  top  of  the  beam ?  I don't  understand

Comment: "Perpendicular to {something}" means "at right angles to {something}".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting something mixed up in your head here.

The shear force is travelling in the vertical direction (up/down).

The segment perpendicular to that shear force is the horizontal component (left/ right) AKA the top and bottoms of the I beam.  In this section the shear flow is linear on the drawing.

The centre section is going vertically, therefore it is parallel to the shear; and it shows the shear flow acting parabolically.

To summarize; both the notes and photo are correct; something in your interpretation was just misunderstood.